# How can i reduce the size of .so libraries in 64-bit apk?

Tags: android, 64-bit, .so

Here is my case, the 32-bit .apk's size is 65MB, and the 64-bit .apk's size is 86MB!
It is too large. What I have done is only change the `abi` configuration in `build.gragle`.

Can anyone help me?
There is a additional requirement that the so libraries should not be compressed by set `android:extractNativeLibs="false"` in `Manifest.xml`
Thank you very much!

Comment: did you enable proguard?

Comment: There might not be a whole lot you can do about this. The code density is simply worse for AArch64 than for AArch32 a lot of the time. E.g. there are no Thumb instructions in AArch64 IIRC.